# Process to apply for NSNP stream - Canada

Tags: canada, immigration, canadian-citizens

Here is the two step process provided in this [link](http://novascotiaimmigration.com/move-here/application-forms/#express-entry) to apply for "NOVA SCOTIA DEMAND: EXPRESS ENTRY".

I would like to confirm, if I need to send applications at two different destinations at a time, as mentioned below:

My question:

Am I suppose to send *NSNP application form* to "*Nova Scotia Office of Immigration*" address(only)?

or

Am I suppose to send *NSNP application form* to "*Nova Scotia Office of Immigration*" address as well as  (*CIC form with photocopy + NSNP appication*) to "*Citizenship and Immigration Canada, Centralized Intake office*" address(as well)?

Please help me!!!

Comment: @mkennedy any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I don't know why I didn't understand this before (end of week? Sleep deprivation?), but [this document](http://novascotiaimmigration.com/wp-content/uploads/AppGuide-NSNP-NSDEE-31Dec2014-English.pdf) states quite clearly in the introduction, second paragraph:

> There are two application routes to Nova Scotia Demand: Express Entry
>   stream, either you apply directly to Nova Scotia Office of Immigration
>   (NSOI) or you have been selected from the Express Entry pool by the
>   NSOI. **In either case the principal applicant will need to submit a
>   complete application to NSOI.**

So, if you've already applied to the national Citizenship and Immigration Canada (CIC) Express Entry process, send copies of that application as part of your NSOI application.

This is also stated on the [originating page](http://novascotiaimmigration.com/move-here/application-forms/#express-entry):

> STEP 2: Complete the CIC forms and provide photocopies with your NSNP [Nova Scotia 
>   Nominee Program] application.

This is specifically for the Nominee Program, where Nova Scotia thinks you'll be an excellent addition to the province and tells the national government, "Hey, we want this person!"

From what I can find, Nova Scotia can also look in the CIC Express Entry database for applicants who've stated they would like to emigrate to Nova Scotia and if the province likes what they see, invite them to apply or ask the federal agency to include them in the draw. In this latter case, I'm not sure if you have to directly apply to NSOI as well.

Comment: send copies of that application? I have applied for CIC  express entry online. So, I did not get you when you say: "send copies".

Comment: Was there a summary page or pages? Otherwise, I would think that they mean copies of any supporting docimentation that you had to upload.

Comment: As mentioned: "you have been selected from the Express Entry pool by the NSOI.", I prefer sending to NSOI office after selection from express entry pool, Because am running short of IETLS score card(only 1 copy). Does it add any value if i apply to NSOI office before first draw of express entry pool?